# Drop in Last Data Point in Grafana Graph

Tags: grafana

I have my graphs in Grafana automatically updating every few seconds. The last data point on the right drops down temporaily as data comes in. The correct value is eventually shown, but it's low for a few updates. Is this normal? Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

Probably, this will help. Actually, it depends on what type of datasource you use. Some of them, like Elasticsearch, have option "Trim edges".
[image: grafana_incomplete_metrics]

Comment: I tried setting the delay from a few seconds to several minutes and refreshed after changing but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding/updating Anna's answer: There is now a dashboard-wide setting for "Now Delay" to avoid requesting recent data that might not show up yet. Note, you'll see this delay reflected in your time picker.
[image: dashboard settings showing now delay]